# How to get local rotation from a reference 'zero' quaternion and the global rotation quaternion

Tags: opengl, math, rotation, tracking, quaternions

I am displaying characters on a screen connected to a flystick (3D tracking object). My goal is to move the characters according to device input.

I noticed the 'zero' of the device (corresponding to the default position) is not corresponding to a not rotated quaternion of my characters. When moving the device, my character moves around some other axis (probably world's) than the device's. So I added a synchronising function which registers the quaternion rotation of my device when it should be at the default position, but now I have no idea how to combine this reference quaternion with the actual quaternion I receive from the device when it moves in order to rotate my character as I intend.

Here is how i am using the quaternions with OpenGL :

```
glm::quat rotation = QAccumulative.getQuat(); 
glm::mat4 matrix_rotation = glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
object_transform *= matrix_rotation;
Model *= object_transform;
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
```

It works fine with keyboard and mouse if I rotate my objects with this method:

```
rotate(float angleX,float angleY,float angleZ) {
  Quaternion worldRotationx( 1.0,0,0, angleZ);   
  Quaternion worldRotationy( 0,1.0,0, angleX);      
  Quaternion worldRotationz( 0,0,1.0, angleY);        
  QAccumulative = worldRotationx * worldRotationy * worldRotationz * QAccumulative;
  QAccumulative.normalise();
}
```

Here is the main loop, where I compute the data from the tracking device:

```
void VRPN_CALLBACK handle_tracker(void* userData, const vrpn_TRACKERCB t ) {
  Vrpn_tracker* current = Vrpn_tracker::current_vrpn_device;
  if (current->calibrating == true) {
    current->reference = Quaternion(t.quat[0],t.quat[1],t.quat[2],t.quat[3]);
    current->reference.normalise();
  } else {
    // translation :
    current->newPosition = sf::Vector3f(t.pos[0],t.pos[1],t.pos[2]);
    current->world->current_object->translate(
      current->newPosition.x - current->oldPosition.x,
      current->newPosition.y - current->oldPosition.y,
      current->newPosition.z - current->oldPosition.z);
    current->oldPosition = current->newPosition;

    // rotation:
    current->newQuat = Quaternion(t.quat[0],t.quat[1],t.quat[2],t.quat[3]);
    current->newQuat.normalise();
    current->world->current_object->QAccumulative = 
      (current->reference.getConjugate() * current->newQuat);
    Quaternion result = current->world->current_object->QAccumulative;
    cout << "result? : " << result.x << result.y << result.z << result.w << endl; 
    // prints something like:
    // x : -0.00207066 y : 0.00186546 z : -0.00165524 w : 0.999995 
    // when position of flystick = default position
  }
}
```

The simple test I do to check the code: I start my program without moving the flystick, (ref quaternion is getting captured) so after the synchronisation the character should be in the default position (not moved) as I haven't touched the flystick.

I did try to multiply my reference by the quaternion received but it seems my character is moving according to local axis.

If someone could shed some light on how I can get the rotation in global axis from these two quaternions it would be great.

Comment: Are people not answering because my question is not clear or just because there is no obvious answer ? Please let me know what i should add in order to get help.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure here. But let me think aloud. You hold the flystick in some orientation which you consider the default orientation, and the tracking systems reports orientation R. You want to get identity transform for this situation, so you should apply the _inverse_ of R, that is R^-1, to all of the tracking orientation inputs X, i.e.  X'=R^-1*X so that for X=R  =>  X'=I.

Comment: @derhass i am not sure how i am supposed to calculate R^-1, the wikipedia article seems to tell that i should compose several structure but isn't there a general formula ?

Comment: The inverse of the quaternion is quite simple. See the [matrix and quaternion FAQ, question 50](http://web.archive.org/web/20041029003853/http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q50). GLM has also an `inverse()` method for quaternions.

Comment: @derhass so i tried what you said, i did ref-1 * newQuat but the result quat doesn't look like identity, i am posting the code corresponding.

Comment: @derhass actually it works fine for the default position but when i rotate the flystick, the object rotates around weird axis.For example starting from default position if i rotate the flystick according to one axis, the quaternion changes all values from all axis.

Comment: is there a way i can synchronise the coordinate system ? it seems that my flystick axis are not the same than the room's...

Comment: You're not getting answers because there's not enough here to answer. My strong guess is that there is a mismatch between what you _think_ the quaternion coming from the device is and what it actually is. The quaternion may be with respect to a reference frame that itself is changing with translation. You must provide a technical spec of the device. Absent that, you must do some systematic tests like recording how the quaternion output changes while moving the device linearly and rotationally and provide that.  Most likely if you do said testing you'll figure it out yourself.

Comment: One other thing: `Model *= object_transform;` makes it look like you are concat'ing the object transform on each iteration. Unless `Model` is being set to identity somewhere else that we can't see, this is wrong.

Comment: @Gene unfortunatly i can't use the device until monday but when i can i will defenetly add tests to understand what these quats are.

Answer (score 1):

You have different calibrations possible for the flystick that may correspond to what you are expecting, however i suggest you read carefully the documentation about the flystick, your answer must be there.
If you are using ART tracking, page 124 of the User manual will help you.

Comment: i am using ART indeed, let me take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Change multiplication order. If you rotate first, than do it last if last than do it first.

The hidden problem of your question, we don't know your transformation notation.

Your rotation can transform from World To Object frame or from Object to world. Depending of notation , exact transformation will be different.

Comment: i am trying to do a rotation around the object's axis so it is what you call from World To Object.